# How to calculate solar panels' energy yield in kWh and for electronic devices in Python

Tags: python, int, calculation

In this example it is assumed that one solar panel produces 175 Wh energy a day. TV's power consumption is 80 watts and one LED light bulb 1.8 watts.

The equation to calculate device's watts per hour is: device's power in watts * hours in use. https://www.parkedinparadise.com/device-calculations/

The output should be like this:

> How many solar panels' energy yield do you want to calculate?
>
> 3
>
> That number of panels gives 0.51 kWh of energy each day.
> That is equal to watching the TV for 10.2 hours or having 25.5 led bulbs on for 10 hours per day.

I've tried to build int / input / float logics but honestly don't know where to start with this problem.

```
panels = input("How many solar panels' energy yield do you want to calculate?\n")
solarpanels = int(panels)
```

(This is unfortunately all I could start with. I don't understand how to break down the equation in Python functions and could not find a related post)

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"*

Answer (score 0):

```
DAYLY_ENERGY_PER_PANEL_IN_WH = 175
TV_CONSUMPTION = 80
LIGHT_BULB_CONSUMPTION = 1.8

panels = input("How many solar panels' energy yield do you want to calculate?\n")
solarpanels = int(panels)

energy_generated_dayly = DAYLY_ENERGY_PER_PANEL_IN_WH * solarpanels

print(f"That number of panels gives {energy_generated_dayly / 1000} kWh of energy each day. "
      f"That is equal to watching the TV for {energy_generated_dayly / TV_CONSUMPTION} hours "
      f"or having {energy_generated_dayly / (LIGHT_BULB_CONSUMPTION * 10)} led bulbs on for 10 hours per day.")
```